# Using iphlpapi.dll's method "GetAdaptersInfo" under linux

Tags: c#, linux, dll, mono, adapter

I have to port an application from a company. It was built with C# in the .net framework. The platform I'm porting to is Linux -- previously the application only ran on Windows.

This application uses the method `GetAdaptersInfo` from *iphlpapi.dll*, which I obviously can't use under Linux. I looked for an equivalent library in Linux, but didn't find any.

Question: Is there an equivalent method to `GetAdaptersInfo` that I can use in my code when running it on Mono?

Perhaps someone has another idea of how I could handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the closest thing is `getifaddrs`, which lets you get a list of network interfaces.